# How to formulate GroupJoin() statement

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I have a database that looks (simplified) like this:

```
var reports = new[] {
    new { ReportId = 1, Title = "Report A" },
    new { ReportId = 2, Title = "Report B" },
};

var testCases = new[] {
    new { TestId = 1, Title = "Test A" },
    new { TestId = 2, Title = "Test B" },
    new { TestId = 3, Title = "Test C" },
    new { TestId = 4, Title = "Test D" },
    new { TestId = 5, Title = "Test E" },
};

var testRuns = new[] {
    new { TestId = 1, ReportId = 1 },
    new { TestId = 2, ReportId = 1 },
    new { TestId = 1, ReportId = 2 },
    new { TestId = 2, ReportId = 2 },
    new { TestId = 3, ReportId = 2 },
    new { TestId = 4, ReportId = 2 },
};
```

As a result, I'd like to get a list of `testCases` grouped with the corresponding `reports`, i.e.:

```
Test A => [Report A, Report B]
Test B => [Report A, Report B]
Test C => [Report B]
Test D => [Report B]
Test E => []
```

I'm not sure how to formulate this in either SQL or LINQ. I think I need a group join or a left outer join or however it is called, but I couldn't figure out the correct syntax yet. I tried something like this, but still miss a part:

```
var result = tests.GroupJoin(reports, t => t.TestId, ???, (t, rs) => new { Test = t, Reports = rs });
```

Or maybe there is an entirely different way to formulate that query.

EDIT: Not every entry in `testCases` is referenced in `testRuns`.

Comment: what version of sql are you working on? mysql, tsql, oracle?

Comment: The DB is on a Microsoft SQL Server but so far I used the Entity Framework as abstraction layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can live without a GroupJoin you can do it with 2 simple joins and a `GroupBy` like this:

```
var temp = from c in testCases
           join ru in testRuns
           on c.TestId equals ru.TestId into left
           from l in left
           join re in reports 
           on l.ReportId equals re.ReportId into foo
           from f in foo
           select new {
                Test = c.Title,
                Report = f
           };
//Dump only in LinqPad!            
temp.GroupBy(x => x.Test).Dump();
```

/EDIT: If you also want the empty results, you need to use `DefaultIfEmpty()`:

```
public class Report
{
    public int ReportId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

public class TestCase
{
    public int TestId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

public class TestRun
{
    public int TestId { get; set; }
    public int ReportId { get; set; }
}
var temp = from c in testCases
           join ru in testRuns
           on c.TestId equals ru.TestId into left
           from l in left.DefaultIfEmpty(new TestRun())
           join re in reports 
           on l.ReportId equals re.ReportId into foo
           from f in foo.DefaultIfEmpty()
           select new {
                Test = c.Title,
                Report = f 
           };

temp.Dump();
```

- Demo Code: http://share.linqpad.net/t3osbj.linq
- Strongly Typed Demo with DefaultIfempty: http://share.linqpad.net/fsov4p.linq
- Loosly typed example with DefaultIfEmpty: http://share.linqpad.net/7k2lq4.linq

Comment: Unfortunately, I have the same problem as with the other answer in that ``testCases`` that have no report don't appear in the result. Any way to fix that with your method? Sorry for not being more clear in the question.

Comment: Yes. This is possible. Give me a few minutes to edit my result.

Comment: @fschoenm Done. Check my updated answer. This will also give you a record with "Test E" and Report `null`. I have provided an example with strongly typed objects, and one with Anonymous objects.

Comment: Thank you. This seems to do what I wanted although it's more complex than I had hoped for. My real-life structure are more complicated than my example so I'd require a lot more joins. Maybe it would be a better approach try to align the database structure somewhat to that problem.

Comment: I'd strongly advise against changing your datamodel because a query "looks" complicated. Remeber, that this is just a mock up. You can always split linq queries in smaller subquieries due to deferred execution. Make exessive use of comments in your code.

Comment: OK, maybe I just need to wrap my head around the model and the SQL/LINQ syntax. Both are new to me, so I'm hitting a lot of walls right now. At least your answer helped me in one regard. Thanks again :-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need group join for this. This will give you what you need. The result would contain a test id along with the reports associated with it.

```
var result = testRuns.GroupBy(tr => tr.TestID)
                     .Select(t => new { 
                                       TestID = t.Key,
                                       Reports = t.Select(r => r.ReportID).ToList()
                                      });
```

Comment: In my actual case, there can be entries in ``testCases`` that are not referenced in ``testRuns`` so maybe my example could be improved. How would the query look to get a result for all ``testCases``?